# What is meant by intercepting a Python call in the sys.exit documentation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exit, sys

In the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.exit), it is said that it is possible to intercept the exit call at the outer level. So what does "intercept at the outside level" actually mean here? 
More specifically, what is meant by intercepting a call?

Comment: Subtle semantic node: the documentation refers to intercepting the exit *attempt*, not the call to `exit`. It's the exception raised by `exit` you can intercept/catch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that an `except SystemExit` will catch the raised exception thereby intercepting the attempted call at exiting Python. `sys.exit` is implemented by raising [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit), which you can handle.

Using the appropriate `except` clause:

```
from sys import exit
try:
    exit("Exiting")
except SystemExit as e:
    print("Well, no you're not.")
```

works just fine and continues on with execution. You intercepted it.

As @chepner notes, the call isn't being intercepted; the call to `exit` is completed. The resulting exception is intercepted by the except handler you provide.

Comment: So this means that, left un-intercepted, the call will go through and the program will exit, right?